# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when adding a script to a .html file

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to add a script into my .html file it shows me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in the console of the browser and of course it doesn't run any script.

I am 100% sure it fails because of me importing the confetti package, here's the code (scripts.js):

```
import confetti from "https://esm.run/canvas-confetti@1";

const easter_egg_left = document.getElementById('dot_left');
const easter_egg_right = document.getElementById('dot_right');

easter_egg_left.onclick = function() {
    confetti({ // # NOTE: read about configs in js and learn how this actually works
        particleCount: 150,
        angle: 45,
        origin: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0.5
        }
    })
};

easter_egg_right.onclick = function() {
    confetti({ // # NOTE: read about configs in js and learn how this actually works
        particleCount: 150,
        angle: -45,
        origin: {
            x: 1,
            y: 0.5
        }
    })
};
```

I have tried what helped others: created a package.json with "type" = module inside, made the .js file into .mjs, tried adding scripts differently and using "type" in their parameters. I don't think this is wrong, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to handle this:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script type="module" src="scripts.js"></script>

Comment: Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Evgenii/Desktop/isaenko.site%20files/isaenko.site-files/scripts.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Comment: Loading scripts from `file://` URLs is now the problem you're experiencing. Use a local lightweight HTTP server (or an HTTP server wherever you want).

Comment: I just uploaded my files to the server and the script did work.. a few times. Then stopped. but This Guy pointed that out correctly, I guess

Comment: Keep in mind that this is scripting within an environment, the browser. It's not programming, not compiling, so it's good to know that and work within those constraints.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: yep, realized it when I launched it from the web. Also fixed it not working. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you reference its a module like this

```
<script type="module" src="scripts.js"></script>
```